# Are squash bugs a pepper pest?

Tags: vegetables, pests, insects, peppers, pest-damage

So, I grew some zucchini and the squash bugs finally proliferated on it. Today I was in the garden and I saw that there were squash bugs hanging out on my chili pepper plant, which is by the zucchini (it's probably half Carolina Reaper, and half something else, but it was supposed to be a Carolina Reaper).

Are they just resting themselves there, or do they actually feed on chili pepper plants? Watching them, they just looked like they were hanging out, and I didn't see any damage, but there were a lot of squash bugs (all of them were fully mature bugs in appearance).

I'm not looking for advice on squash bug control (just on whether or not they feed on peppers).

Sorry. No pictures right now. I need to charge my camera.

Comment: I've never heard of that before. Ever. Undoubtedly you know what squash bug damage looks like, so you will be able to tell soon whether they have fed (I highly doubt they will).

Comment: I looked for bugs on the pepper plant on Friday and I didn't find any. I could be wrong, but I'm guessing they were just hanging out to dry while the squash plants dried, since I watered the whole area right before I saw them. They don't bother the squash plants as much when they're wet, I've found. I don't know why there weren't any young ones with them.

Comment: Hi there Shule!  Squash bugs are fairly confined to the curcubits.  I think you were right thinking they were hanging out to dry off after you hosed them down. Hubby hosed down a baby bunny the other day that was in the greenhouse/garden.  heh heh heh THAT'S not happening again!  grins!!

Comment: https://www.gardentech.com/blog/pest-id-and-prevention/eliminate-squash-bugs-from-your-garden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no cases I can find that squash bugs feed on anything in the Nightshade family (such as a pepper). It's unusual for groups of them to congregate on any plant other than a food host, so I don't know what was going on there, but they wouldn't be eating the pepper.

A few bugs here and there throughout the vicinity (on adjacent plants) in normal.

Comment: Yeah. They didn't eat the peppers. I think they were just roosting on them waiting for things to dry after the sprinkler got everything wet (or something; they really liked perching on it for some unknown reason). I moved the pepper plant, and a few straggling squash bugs persisted on the plant for a few days, but when I got them off (without killing them), they didn't come back.